# Converting a string id to an object id inside an array of objects in MongoDB aggregation

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm working on a record which looks something like this:

```
"newAssessmentReport": [
    {
        "_id": "63be6627774d304bb4456d09",
        "poll_report": [],
        "pitch_ids": [],
        "assessment_report_status": "Open",
        "founder_id": "63bd4c19e27b915442530930",
        "funding_deal_id": "63be5f40774d304bb444c785",
        "investment_report": [
            {
                "user_id": "62872d5b538b063eb86dd687",
            },
            {
                "user_id": "62872d5b538b063eb86dd700",
            },
            {
                "user_id": "62872d5b538b063eb86dd444",
            }
         ]
    }
```

Here, we have an array of object, where each object has a key named "investment_report", inside which, we have an array of object consisting of user_id. I have to convert that user_id into an objectId format. After which I want to use lookup to extract user data from these IDs. A table named "users" would be utilized for data extraction.

How can I achieve that? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like [$toObjectid](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toObjectId/#-toobjectid--aggregation-) might be useful

Answer (score 0):

to convert it, use [$toObjectId](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toObjectId/)

```
db.newAssessmentReport.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$investment_report", //deconstruct to get user_id
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "users",
      let: {
        user_id: {
          $toObjectId: "$investment_report.user_id",
        },
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $eq: ["$_id", "$$user_id"],
            },
          },
        },
        {
          $project: {
            _id: 1,
            name: 1,
          },
        },
      ],
      as: "investment_report.user_id",
    },
  },

  //to keep element of users in object || optional
  {
    $unwind: "$investment_report.user_id",
  },
  //reverse object
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      poll_report: {
        $first: "$poll_report",
      },
      pitch_ids: {
        $first: "$pitch_ids",
      },
      assessment_report_status: {
        $first: "$assessment_report_status",
      },
      founder_id: {
        $first: "$founder_id",
      },
      funding_deal_id: {
        $first: "$funding_deal_id",
      },
      investment_report: {
        $push: "$investment_report",
      },
    },
  },
]);
```

try it in [MONGO-PALYGROUND](https://mongoplayground.net/p/PHRgxJyfNRL)